# Is it possible to use mailgun.com as a SMTP server for personal outgoing emails, including the correct error return emails?

Tags: email, smtp

I am using mailgun.com for occassional mass-mailings. Would it be possible to also use it for sending personal emails from me and my wife? The specific problem is that email errors (e.g. "Recipient not found on the server") are only available in the mailgun console and I'd like for them to be received as an error emails sent back to the sender (as is the case with "standard" personal email services). Is it possible to set this up at mailgun.com?

Alternatively, is there a cheap (or even free) SMTP server available for sending emails from the custom domain I own?

(Note that RECEIVING emails to our domain is not a problem, we have that solved using email redirection on my domain.)

Detailed explanation of our setup and reasoning: Behind the scenes, we are both using personail gmail accounts (e.g. me@gmail.com and wife@gmail.com) but we don't advertise these anywhere and our "public" email addresses are me@mydomain.com and wife@mydomain.com. Mydomain.com uses Cloudflare email redirection to redirect our incoming emails back to our Gmail inboxes. We used "Send mail as" GMail feature to send emails as "me@mydomain.com" and "wife@mydomain.com" through smtp.gmail.com but this solution requires us to have "Less secure apps" enabled on our Google accounts and Google seems to be phasing this solution out. The fact that our "real" Gmail addresses are visible in the email headers is not a problem for us.

Originally, we've used free "legacy" Google Workspace accounts on mydomain.com but those are now also being phased out by Google. So we are looking for a SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

I have found that smtp2go.com (which provides very similar services to mailgun.com) provides this option. Your SMTP account can be configured (in the "Advanced" tab) so that bounced email reports are delivered back to the sender's mailbox (or to different mailbox). Additionally, smtp2go's services are free if you send less than 1000 emails monthly so this seems like perfect solution to my problem.